# template <pointer> get type of object pointed to

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I'm trying to write a generic function to count bits in an array.  I'm trying to use **template** to define the functions.

```
template <typename TYPE_T>
size_t countBits (TYPE_T testeeA, const size_t sizeA)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t item = 0; item < sizeA; item++)
    {
        for (TYPE_T bit = 1; bit != 0; bit += bit)
        {
            if ((testeeA[item] & bit) == bit) count++;
        }
    }
    return (count);
}
```

But I need the second **TYPE_T** to be `char` when **TYPE_T** is `char*`.

I tried `typename TYPE_T *` in the **template** argument but VS2012 C++ barfed.

I can write this in preprocesser macro:

```
#define COUNTBITS(TYPE_T) \
size_t countBits (TYPE_T * testeeA, const size_t sizeA) \
{ size_t count = 0; \
for (size_t item = 0; item < sizeA; item++) \
{ for (TYPE_T bit = 1; bit != 0; bit += bit) \
. . .
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this:

```
template <typename TYPE_T>
size_t countBits (const TYPE_T* testeeA, const size_t sizeA) {...}
```

This way, if you pass a `char*` pointer to `countBits`, `TYPE_T` resolves to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of:

1. Make the template argument a pointer:

   ```
   template <typename TYPE_T>
   std::size_t countBits(TYPE_T* testeeA, ...);
   ```
2. Use `std::remove_pointer`:

   ```
   for (typename std::remove_pointer<TYPE_T>::type bit = 1; bit != 0; bit += bit)
   ```